# JQuery Code to Expand All in Nested Gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a working javascript function to individually expand/collapse dynamically generated nested gridviews from the parent gridview when the respective buttons are clicked. I would like to add additional functionality to expand/collapse all of the nested gridviews upon clicking a separate button. The way I am attempting this is using jquery to iterate through all instances of the expand/collapse buttons and click them. With my implementation however, only the final gridview, gets expanded.

Here is the function that executes to expand/collapse individual nested children, and this is what in effect gets called by the "clicking" in my jquery attempt:

```
function expandcollapse(obj, row) {
        var div = document.getElementById(obj);
        var img = document.getElementById('img' + obj);
        if (div.style.display == "none") {
            div.style.display = "block";
            if (row == 'alt') {
                img.src = "minus.gif";
            }
            else {
                img.src = "minus.gif";
            }
            img.alt = "Close to view other Workflows";
        }
        else {
            div.style.display = "none";
            if (row == 'alt') {
                img.src = "plus.gif";
            }
            else {
                img.src = "plus.gif";
            }
            img.alt = "Expand to show Tasks";
        }
    }
```

This is what my jquery to expand/collapse all consists of:

```
function expandAll() {
    $('img[id^="imgdiv"]').each(function(i, obj) {
        $(this).trigger('click');
    });
}
```

And finally the ASP.NET code I am trying to expand:

```
...
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<img src='plusbutton.png' onclick='expandAll();'>" >
<ItemTemplate>
    <a href="javascript:expandcollapse('div<%# Eval("WorkflowID") %>', 'one');">
        <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("WorkflowID") %>" alt="Click to show/hide Tasks for Workflow <%# Eval("WorkflowID") %>" width="9" border="0" src="plus.gif" />
    </a>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("WorkflowID") %>' CommandName="EditRow" ForeColor="#8C4510" runat="server">Edit</asp:LinkButton>| 
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row?');" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("WorkflowID") %>' CommandName="DeleteRow" ForeColor="#8C4510" runat="server" CausesValidation="false">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbUpdate" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("WorkflowID") %>' CommandName="UpdateRow" ForeColor="#8C4510" runat="server">Update</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCancel" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("WorkflowID") %>' CommandName="CancelUpdate" ForeColor="#8C4510" runat="server" CausesValidation="false">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
</EditItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbInsert" ValidationGroup="Insert"
        runat="server" ForeColor="#8C4510" CommandName="InsertRow">Insert
    </asp:LinkButton>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
...
```

Upon clicking the button that calls the jquery function, all of the nested gridviews should expand/collapse. What I have currently is only taking effect on the last nested gridview.

Comment: You applied loop to image object. `$('img[id^="imgdiv"]').each(function(i, obj) {`. Instead it should be for it's children.

Comment: @randomSoul The images don't have children; they are children of the anchor tag. I believe I still want to iterate through the images, it's just a matter of why the expand does not occur on all of the intermediary images instead of only on the last one.

Comment: @jmglygnn - I don't really understand `asp` code, but within the `expandall` function, you are selecting the `img` whose `id` begins with `imgdiv` and I can see only one `img` tag which have this `id`.